# Set system time zone in Linux

Tags: c, linux

Are there any functions in C language to set system time in Linux?
I have to set my system time zone also.
I other words, if my timezone is IST, can I set it to UTC?

Comment: Look at `hwclock` source code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the time zone before calling strftime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620188/how-can-i-set-the-time-zone-before-calling-strftime)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`stime`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stime) to set the time,and [`tzset`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tzset) to set the timezone.

Note that the `tz` (timezone) parameter to [`settimeofday`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/settimeofday) is *obsolete*.

Answer (score 3):

The default time zone, used by processes that don't have a `TZ` variable in their environment, is decided by the contents of `/etc/localtime`. Find the time zone you want in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` and copy or symlink it.

```
rm /etc/localtime
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT /etc/localtime
```

There are some interactive tools to help you pick a time zone, but they vary by distribution (e.g. Debian's `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`)

Comment: There is, apparently, also the `timedatectl set-timezone Etc/UTC` command which updates the localtime for you. On Debian based systems it is apparently recommended to always use the `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` command, since this also updates the (legacy) `/etc/timezone` file in addition to the `/etc/localtime` file as [described here](https://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges#Check_Configured_Timezone).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timezone by using this

```
setenv("TZ", "PST8PDT", 1);
tzset();
```